# How can I play sound in a method?

Tags: java, android

I am creating a game where whenever user clicks the right picture he increases the score and in addition to that I want to play a beep sound when accomplished. How can I do that?

Here is the related method:

```
 public void increaseScore(View view){
    score=score+1;
    scoreText.setText("Score: "+score);
```

How can I implement sound in this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **MediaPlayer** class for this.

Globe Variable:

```
  MediaPlayer mp;
```

Add it in **onCreate**:

```
 mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound);
```

Here the function:

```
     public void increaseScore(View view)
     {
        score=score+1;
        scoreText.setText("Score: "+score);
           try {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                       mp.stop();
                         mp.release();
                         mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound);
                        }
                    mp.start();
                    } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works!